# Disable MIUI automatic updates setting on each reboot

Tags: settings, ota-update, automation, miui

I have a Xiaomi Redmi smartphone, and looking for a way to perform the following task on each boot or every day:

- Settings - System app updates - Settings - Automatic updates - Disable automatic updates

MIUI does turn system app updates back on, quite frequently. My banking application doesn't like rooting, and I'd like to avoid the hassle anyways.

The application I am looking for would be the MIUI/Android equivalent of "O&O ShutUp10++" for Windows. This application disables Windows Updates every time the OS decides to turn it back on.

Please let me know if you can find a way to do it.

Comment: Welcome Android Enthusiasts. Please note that questions directly asking for app recommendations are off-topic. Instead, we prefer the asker to just state the underlying problem that they want to solve and not put any restrictions on apps only. Otherwise, you might be interested in our sister site, [Software Recommendations Stack Exchange](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/tour) instead. Thanks for your understanding.